# Container Algebraic Data Type in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections, algebraic-data-types

Not very familiar with Scala's type system, but here's what I'm trying to do.

I have a function that tries to filter people by first and last name, and if that fails filters by first name only.

```
case class Person(id: Int, first: String, last:String)
def(people: Set[Person], firstName: String, lastName: String): (MatchResult, Set[Person]) =
  val (both, firstOnly) = people.filter(_.first == firstName).partition(_.last == lastName)

  (both.nonEmpty, firstOnly.nonEmpty) match {
    case (true, _) => (BothMatch, both)
    case (false, true) => (FirstOnly, firstOnly)
    case (_, _) => (NoMatch, Set[Person]())
  }
```

Right now I am returning the filtered `Set` along with an Algebraic Data Type informing the caller which filter's results were used.

```
sealed trait MatchResult
case object BothMatch extends MatchResult
case object FirstOnly extends MatchResult
case object NoMatch extends MatchResult
```

However, returning a tuple of the `Set` + `MatchResult` doesn't present a very nice contract for the caller.  I'm wondering how I can store my filtered results *in* my `MatchResult`.

I thought I could simply change to:

```
sealed trait MatchResult extends Set[People]
case object BothMatch extends MatchResult
case object FirstOnly extends MatchResult
case object NoMatch extends MatchResult
```

But the compiler tells me that I `must implement abstract member iterator: Iterator[A]`

I'm not sure if I should try to extend `Set` or somehow make `MatchResult` a `case class` that takes a set as a constructor argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use case classes to store any matches as a member.

```
sealed trait MatchResult
case class BothMatch(results:Set[Person]) extends MatchResult
case class FirstOnly(results:Set[Person]) extends MatchResult
case object NoMatch extends MatchResult
```

In Scala, [Set is is trait that has abstract members](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Set.html) that must be implemented by any implementing class, and that's why you are receiving that error.

In your implementation, you could use these classes by,

```
(both.nonEmpty, firstOnly.nonEmpty) match {
    case (true, _) => BothMatch(both)
    case (false, true) => FirstOnly(firstOnly)
    case (_, _) => NoMatch
  }
```