# Why the compiler does not recognize the properties?

Tags: scala

I have the following code, that does not compile:

```
sealed trait PcpPair

case class PcpHead(key: String, value: String) extends PcpPair

case class PcpFieldValue(field: String, value: String) extends PcpPair

  private val decodeHead: List[PcpHead] => String = heads =>
    decodePair(heads) { (acc, value) =>
      acc |+| value.key |+| ":" |+| value.value |+| "\n"
    }

  private val decodePair: List[PcpPair] => ((String, PcpPair) => String) => String = pcpList => fnPcp =>
    pcpList.foldLeft("")(fnPcp)
```

The compiler complains:

```
 value key is not a member of com.sweetsoft.PcpPair
[error]       acc |+| value.key |+| ":" |+| value.value |+| "\n"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are trying to access `.key` on trait `PcpPair`, which doesn't have any members except those inherited from `Any`. Obviously, this must fail. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: In Haskell, you can define a type as the following: `data Bool = True | False`. How to do it in Scala

Comment: With sealed traits and [case classes/objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47841374/container-algebraic-data-type-in-scala). But that's a separate question. Your comment does not seem to clarify the current question.

Comment: I am trying to archive, that the first parameter of ` decodePair` can pass either `PcpHead` or `PcpFieldValue` type.

Comment: Then add `def value: String` to the common interface `trait PcpPair`. That would give you access to `value`. Since PcpFieldValue does not have `key`, you obviously cannot ask any `PcpPair` for a `key`.

Answer (score 0):

`PcpPair` has no `value` member. `PcpHead` and `PcpFieldValue` do. But `decodePair` insists on accepting a list of `PcpPair`.

You need to make `value` somehow visible at the `PcpPair` level, I suppose, or you have to match the case classes explicitly in the function passed to fold.

(E.g. in Haskell you have to write explicit matching rules, too.)